# How to build EMF radiation protection

Tags: shielding, laptop, radiation

I've recently started to use my laptop more and more on my lap and I'm worried about exposire to radiation emmited by the laptop.
I keep it at a distance of about 10cm but still...

I was wondering if there are any effective ways to build an EMF radiation protection without spending lots of money.

There are commercial solutions like [this](https://www.defendershield.com/defenderpad-laptop-radiation-heat-shield) but nobody sells anything like that in my country and if I order it, with transport fees, customs taxes, etc can get quite expensive.

So what materials can you use (wire mesh, led foil, mylar foil, etc) and how you can arrange them in order to build an effective EMF radiation protection or any harmful radiation coming from a laptop?

Comment: Tin foil, shaped in the form of a hat, is traditional. Your laptop isn't emitting ***harmful*** radiation. It radiates. Just nothing to worry over. If you remain concerned, distance is your friend, as it is reduced by the square of distance. So twice as far away is four times better. Building a Faraday cage around it would make it hard to use. And wrapping it in lead foil might, if thick enough, offer some protection against gamma. But there is no way that's a problem. And it takes a lot of lead anyway. Look up "cross section measured in 'barns'" if you want to read something technical.

Comment: You are probably receiving more radiation through your head by all the RF signals that are passing through the air. Even the Wi-fi signals are flying through your brains as we speak right now. And literally millions of neutrinos have flown through your brain by the time you've read this comment.

Comment: @jonk: _Tin foil, shaped in the form of a hat, is traditional._ Funny. But I'm not trying to stop aliens trying to read my mind. In all seriousness, are you saying there is absolutely no danger in keeping my laptop on my lap for long period of times with wifi on and so on? I'm not talking about environment radiation which can't quite be avoided. Am talking about having an antenna on my body for long times. Are you guys also suggesting to sleep with my phone under my pillow at night? Is that safe too? (without the tin foil around my head of course).

Comment: Seriously.  There's no danger to you from "radiation" from your laptop.  It emits electromagnetic waves of all kinds, but nothing that is generally classified as "radiation" like you would get from a radioactive material like uranium or radon.  The most dangerous thing from a laptop or smart phone are the unnatural positions people hold while using the things.  You are more likely to develop problems with your posture and spine than any kind of "radiation" related anything.

Comment: The only harmful thing that your laptop emits during sleep ist the noise of its fans. My new laptop woke me up a few times because windows decided to install updates - resulting in a fan noise spike.

Comment: Yes, Pete. It is safe. Had you been using an old TV set which depends on high voltages, then there would be legitimate concerns. A specialty of mine is radiation physics, nuclides, and scintillator systems. There are valid concerns for some products. But laptops are about as safe as things get today. There are also stringent standards for emissions, not because of health concerns, but because of interference with other devices. If I had time, we could go through each detail one at a time. And you'd agree then, I think.

Comment: Using your laptop on your lap actually does hold one danger (at least for men.) Sperm production drops when the gonads are heated.  You can (somewhat) reduce your reproductive capabilities by keeping them too warm.  Not enough to be used as a form of contraception, but maybe enough to delay your plans to start a family.

Comment: @TurboJ:  Then turn the freaking thing off when not in use.  Do you really need to save a couple of seconds waiting for it to start up at the cost of it waking you at night?

Comment: True, but not because of radiation specifically.

Comment: @JRE.. that depends on what you are watching on your laptop. ;D

Comment: I love the way advertisers write: "blocks up to virtually 100% of harmful laptop radiation." How wishy-washy can you get?

Comment: What price on safe testacles eh?

Comment: A cookie sheet, or TV tray.

Comment: @JRE WAIT!! I can sell a product that "blocks virtually 100% of harmful laptop radiation?" ???? Hmm... I'm in the wrong business. I'm going to create a new website and sell products that "blocks virtually 100% of harmful radiation" on everything from flashlights to laptops. Wasted my life sinking hours into lower-margin ... Need to shift gears and make some real money!!  "WWW.STOPHARMFULRADIATIONNOW.COM" I've been so stupid all these years....

Answer (score 3):

If you ask pretty much anyone the EMI radiation from your laptop is not likely to do you any physical damage.

Having said that, someone somewhere will likely expose some rats to a ridiculous amount of radiation and the rats will get sick, and they will claim laptops cause cancer... So in reality, you can't claim anything is safe.

However, fretting about it, can make you sicker than the radiation itself. As such, if it worries you, I suggest a quick and cheap solution.

Go visit your local hardware store and buy a sheet of foil-backed foam insulation, like [silverboard](https://www.amvicsystem.com/silverboard-rigid-foam-insulation).

[image]

It comes in big sheets so you can make a few lightweight laptop sized "trays" that you can use to not only provide an EMI shield, but also stop the heat from the laptop from cooking your legs.